# How to parse a string and get once per once a substring?

Tags: java, string, substring

I want to make a program how it returns an ArrayList with each substring (from a String) in order.

```
     static boolean tropChangements(String branche, int ocurrTaches) {
        ArrayList dispositif = new ArrayList();
        String pub = "[public]";
        String priv = "[private]";
        String brancheDecoup;
        int ptVirg = branche.indexOf(" ; ");
        for(int i = 0; i<ocurrTaches; i++) {
            brancheDecoup = [...] //use ptVirg
            if (brancheDecoup.contains(pub)) {
                dispositif.add("public");
            } else if (branche.contains(priv)) {
                dispositif.add("private");
            }
        }

        //[...] It's OK here
    }
```

So, I want in "BrancheDecoup" only the first occurence of my substring and the next one, next one etc. (The end of String is with a ".")

My String, for example : 
EcrireNomEtudiant[public] ; EntrerMDP[private] ; AvecQui[private] ; ChoisirJour[perso] ; VerifDisponibilites[system] ; AfficherRecupilatif[private] ; EnvoyerLaDemande[system].

And I want this in result -->

In ArrayList : "public", "private", "private", "perso", "private"

Thank you very much in advance.

Best regards,
Vincent.

Comment: Do you know about `String#split` function ? If yes, then try it . Your code will become more easier

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can first split the string and then use regex to match the pattern

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\[(.*?)]");
    String str = "EcrireNomEtudiant[public] ; EntrerMDP[private] ; AvecQui[private] ; ChoisirJour[perso] ; VerifDisponibilites[system] ; AfficherRecupilatif[private] ; EnvoyerLaDemande[system]";

    Function<String, String> finder = s -> {
        Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
        return m.find() ? m.group(1) : null;
    };
    List<String> list = Arrays.stream(str.split(";"))
        .map(finder)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(list);
```

Answer (score 3):

Not sure i understand fully what you're trying to do, but this would give you the output you're expecting:

```
    List<String> dispositif = new ArrayList<>();
    Pattern re = Pattern.compile("\\[(public|private|perso)\\]");
    Matcher matcher = re.matcher(branche);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        dispositif.add(matcher.group(1));
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider [Apache Commons Lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) ***lib*** usage, which makes the above (*@sidgate*) code even more clear.

So, complete listing will be:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;

public class Example {

  static String sample =
      "EcrireNomEtudiant[public] ; EntrerMDP[private] ; AvecQui[private] ; ChoisirJour[perso] ; VerifDisponibilites[system] ; AfficherRecupilatif[private] ; EnvoyerLaDemande[system]";

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    tropChangements(sample);
  }

  static void tropChangements(String branche) {
    List<String> list = Arrays
        .stream(branche.split(";"))
        .map(String::trim)
        .map(s -> StringUtils.substringBetween(s, "[", "]"))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(list);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String sample = "EcrireNomEtudiant[public] ; EntrerMDP[private] ; AvecQui[private] ; ChoisirJour[perso] ; VerifDisponibilites[system] ; AfficherRecupilatif[private] ; EnvoyerLaDemande[system].";
        tropChangements(sample);
    }

    static void tropChangements(String branche) {
        Set<String> dispositif = new HashSet<String>(); // use Set so that there will be no duplicates
        String[] branches = branche.split(";"); // use split method to split string by ";"
        for (String s : branches) { // iterate string
            int indexOfOpen = s.indexOf("["); // get the index of "["
            int indexOfClose = s.lastIndexOf("]"); // get the index of "]"
            if (indexOfOpen > 0 && indexOfClose > 0) { // check if both "[" and "]" is found
                String tmp = s.substring(indexOfOpen + 1, indexOfClose); // get the needed string
                dispositif.add(tmp); //add it to the set
            }
        }
        System.out.println(dispositif); // print the set

    }
}
```

Result : `[perso, private, system, public]`